# Can you get the ratchet mechanism out of a socket wrench by itself? Anyone know where if so?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

Title pretty much says it all; looking for a reversible ratchet hub for a special latch that I'm designing.  Definitely open to any ideas/sources that the community at large might have.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not disassemble a socket set? What's the actual application you have in mind?

Comment: Look at automatic hubs used on some 4wd.

Comment: Every decent socket wrench can be disassembled, because the mechanism is a wear item.

Comment: The comment regarding disassembling a socket wrench is a good one; I didn't know that.  We're looking at latches for a study design project in the southern ocean in winter time;  extremely tricky environment.  I'm especially worried about jamming due to thermal expansion/contraction.  But @JonathanRSwift andTiger Guy, I'll look into disassembly.  Thanks!